# Problema con firebase deploy

Tags: firebase

Hace unos meses tenia un proyecto que subia a firebase usando el firebase tools, hoy quise modificar unas cosas del proyecto y al momento de hacer el deploy me lo sube a otra app, (tengo 2 apps dentro del mismo proyecto).

Recuerdo que habia que hacer un cambio en el archivo firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Pero no recuerdo que cambio era especificamente, alguien podria ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes especificar el sitio de alojamiento en el archivo firebase.json agregando una propiedad de site debajo de la propiedad de hosting, como esta:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "site": "my-site-name"
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva.